# LTSP Thin clients Login problem

Tags: ssh, dhcp, remote-access, ltsp

**The situation is:**

I have created an Ubuntu LTSP 64bit Server with 32 bit clients using steps in this [tutorial](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-create-ubuntu-1104-x64-ltsp-server-32bit-thin-clients).

I used Virtual Box machine as thin client using same procedure in this [tutorial](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/node/31).

Every thing goes well and i could boot normally the thin client till it gets into the ldm login window.

[image]

I entered the client username and password but nothing happens still showing `verifying password. Please wait` then the ldm restart.(**not the system**).

[image]

I tried to make autologin by adding the username and password to the `lts.conf` file but still not working..

I restarted ssh server and dhcp and build the ltsp image again but still hanging in the same problem...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if ltsp.conf located not in image check this:
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=689668

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to get this resolved?
I struggled with this as well.
I had it finally working with a SSSD-LDAP client installed, both on the LTSP server and in the CHROOTed environment.
I also ensured that `pam_mkhomedir.so` was loaded in `/etc/pam.d/common.session`